# Permission denied while installing R package

Tags: 18.04, permissions, r

I've installed R (version 3.6.0) on my ubuntu 18.04 which I run on the windows subsystem WSL.

Now I'm having a problem to install some specific packages. For example `xml2`. When I run the command `install.packages("xml2")`, i get the following error:

```
mv: cannot move '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-xml2/00new/xml2' to '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xml2': Permission denied
ERROR:   moving to final location failed
```

I guess there might be some way to give myself full permission for managing my own stuff, does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Comment: Why not use R for Windows? Alternately install R packages directly from the ppa.

Comment: Since iirc the default version of R in the Ubuntu 18.04 repository is 3.4, please [edit] your question to include how you installed R 3.6.0 (from a PPA? from a 3rd party tarball?)

Answer (score 12):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389028/12101996) suggested on stackoverflow.com worked for me.

> The best way to avoid this is to use the '--no-lock' argument on the command line, e.g.,

```
R CMD INSTALL --no-lock <pkg>
```

> On NFS file systems it is sometimes not obvious what things you have to close. From within R, you can do this from within your command using:

```
install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall R version 3.6.0, and remove the R PPA if there is one from your software sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` by preceding the line containing this PPA with a `#` character to turn it into a comment. Then run `sudo apt update` to refresh your list of available software. Now that you have removed the R packages that don't work, you are ready to install r-base and r-cran-xml2 from the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

To install xml2 R package in Ubuntu 18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install r-base r-cran-xml2
```

This GNU R XML parser package works with XML files using a simple, consistent interface. It's built on top of the 'libxml2' C library.