# Permission denied while installing R package "ps"

Tags: 18.04, r

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 WSL. I originally installed R 3.6 following this guide: [R-CRAN-Linux-Ubuntu-Installation](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#installation). This question is related to: [Permission denied while installing R package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163130/permission-denied-while-installing-r-package). I am writing a new question instead of commenting on the former because I don't have sufficient reputation. I tried to follow the instructions in the only answer in that post, however uninstalling R 3.6 and installing R 3.4 from default ubuntu repositories results in a similar error (below).

Finally, I cannot install `ps` from apt using the same pattern as `r-cran-xml2`, as no such package (`r-cran-ps`) exists on bionic. `r-cran-ps` is available on disco. I am trying to install `ps` because it is a dependency of rlib [TSclust](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSclust/index.html).

I can run R 3.6 on Windows without any problem so I expect this is related to WSL Ubuntu. Any advice or references from others who are familiar with this error is appreciated.

> > ~/code/real-estate-lab/R$ sudo -E R
>
> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes" Copyright (C)
>   2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
>   or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type
>   'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite
>   R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
>   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to
>   quit R.
>
> > install.packages("ps") Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL
>   'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ps_1.3.0.tar.gz' Content type
>   'application/x-gzip' length 261887 bytes (255 KB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 255 KB
>
> * installing *source* package ‘ps’ ...
>   ** package ‘ps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation
>   ** libs
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -Wall px.c -o px
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api-common.c -o api-common.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c common.c -o common.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c extra.c -o extra.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dummy.c -o dummy.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c posix.c -o posix.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api-posix.c -o api-posix.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c linux.c -o linux.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api-linux.c -o api-linux.o
>   gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o ps.so init.o api-common.o common.o extra.o dummy.o posix.o api-posix.o linux.o api-linux.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
>   installing via 'install.libs.R' to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-ps/00new/ps
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>   ** help
>   *** installing help indices
>   ** building package indices
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
>   ** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries mv: cannot move '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-ps/00new/ps' to
>   '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ps': Permission denied ERROR:   moving
>   to final location failed
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>           ‘/tmp/RtmpG1GgKd/downloaded_packages’ Warning message: In install.packages("ps") :   installation of package ‘ps’ had non-zero
>   exit status
>   > q()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the other solution given to the related question you mentioned?

`install.packages("ps", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))`

Note that using `sudo` for installing packages, although a quick workaround, will trap you into having to quit and restart R every time you want to remove or update your packages created in a `sudo` R session.

Comment: Thank you. I think this error is related to machine-specific constraints. Was an engineering laptop built for corporate environment. I continued to have serious challenges with WSL and stopped using it entirely. Using R on Windows itself turned out fine for my case as I just needed to do data analysis.